# How can I define and reference the text that was inputted inside a stringOption text parameter in javascript discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot just reply with the exact message that the user inputted. I have it set up so the command looks like "/tsay text: TextExample" is the stringOption and if it worked it would reply with "TextExample" that the user inputted. Im trying to get the text but I don't really know how. Any help is appreciated since I am new to JavaScript and discord.js. Here is what I have currently

````
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('tsay')
    .setDescription('Replies with the text that was entered (General)')
    .addStringOption(option => 
        option.setName('text')
        .setDescription('Text to be copied')
            .setRequired(true)),

            async execute(interaction, client) {
                const textOption = interaction.getOption('text');
                const Text = textOption.content;
                // Reply with the text
                await interaction.editReply({
                    content: toString(Text)
                });
            } 
}```





I tried searching up how to do it and look at different documentations but I couldn't find anything exactly that could help me solve my issue.
````

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a fix now. I had to reference the options differently. Here is the updated code that worked

```
    const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('tsay')
    .setDescription('Replies with the text that was entered (General)')
    .addStringOption(option => 
        option.setName('text')
        .setDescription('Text to be copied')
            .setRequired(true)),

            async execute(interaction, client) {
                const Text = interaction.options.getString('text');

                // Reply with the text
                await interaction.reply({
                    content: Text
                });
            } 
}
```